# How to convert python dict to 3D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a python dict with n_keys where each value is a 2D array (dim1,dim2).
I want to transfer this into a 3D numpy array of (dim1,dim2,n_keys).
How can I do it fast without a lot of nested loops?

EDIT:
Example:

```
featureMatrix = np.empty((len(featureDict.values()[0]),
       len(featureDict.values()[0][0,:]),
       len(featureDict.keys())))

for k,keys in enumerate(featureDict.keys()):
   value=featureDict[keys]
   for i in range(0,len(value[:,0]),1):
       for j in range(0,len(value[0,:]),1):
           featureMatrix[i,j,k]=value[i,j]
```

Comment: Show us a sample case?

Comment: So the `key` is not used at all?  You just want to collect the `values` arrays into one 3d array?

Answer (score 5):

`dict`-ionaries are unordered so you probably don't want to simply stack them but you can simply stack the values nevertheless with `array3d = np.dstack(somedict.values())`.

Here is some example case:

```
>>> somedict = dict(a = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2),
                    b = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2) + 10,
                    c = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2) + 100,
                    d = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2) + 1000)

>>> array3d = np.dstack(somedict.values())
>>> array3d.shape
(2, 2, 4)
>>> array3d # unordered because of dict unorderedness, order depends for all practical purposes on chance
array([[[  10,    0, 1000,  100],
        [  11,    1, 1001,  101]],

       [[  12,    2, 1002,  102],
        [  13,    3, 1003,  103]]])
```

or in case you want to stack it sorted by the key of the dictionary:

```
>>> array3d = np.dstack((somedict[i] for i in sorted(somedict.keys())))
>>> array3d    # sorted by the keys!
array([[[   0,   10,  100, 1000],
        [   1,   11,  101, 1001]],

       [[   2,   12,  102, 1002],
        [   3,   13,  103, 1003]]])
```